# How do I clear the screen for Python Shell for Python 3.7.2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I clear the screen for the Python Shell?

I am using Python 3.7.2. I know there is a code for clearing the screen in the Python for Windows Terminal. Someone told me to type in "cls" but that returns an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    cls
NameError: name 'cls' is not defined
```

Comment: Easiest but hackiest way is probably to do  `import os; a = os.system("cls");` This just calls out to the shell and runs whatever is in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a sub-process call to cls or clear depending on your OS.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('cls')
```

Alternatively if you're looking to clear the shell without code you can use Control-L.

Comment: Thank you!!, I truly appreciate your help, this is exactly what I was looking for.